# Flash Player goes black when resizing in Chrome (Mac)

Tags: flash, macos, google-chrome, onresize

I've noticed what appears to be a **bug** with *Google Chrome* and *Flash* when resizing on a Mac.

I have an `SWF` file embedded on my page and it does resize when the browser window is resized.

Crazy things happen in *Google Chrome* when I resize the window:

- the Flash screen goes completely black and flickers like a bad TV
  reception.
- One can also see the screen *slide* into place when the resizing is
  done.

There is an example of this on YouTube - *open any video and click on "expand" using Chrome*.

This only seems to happen to me on *Chrome for Mac* (PC is fine). I'm using *Chrome 7.0.517.41* and *Flash Player version 10,1,85,3*.

All other browsers are fine.

*Has anybody else experienced this? And found any solution to this?*

*Seems to be a browser re-draw problem?*

Comment: Yes, we had the exact same problem on Chrome/Mac, but didnt find any solution. Thanks for asking this question, I am really looking forward to the answers.

Comment: http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: bug has been already reported, can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=60341&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS&id=60341